# run aubiopitch continuously on a file descriptor

Tags: audio, sox, audio-analysis, aubio

I'd like to use `aubiopitch` to continuously output the frequency of a signal coming from an input source. Since `aubiopitch` likes to have its input be a file, not a stream, I tried using [process substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html):

```
$ aubiopitch -i <(sox -q -d -t wav -)
```

I'd expect this to output the frequency of the signal being read off of my default audio input device. Instead, I got this:

```
./sox WARN wav: Length in output .wav header will be wrong since can't seek to fix it
AUBIO ERROR: source_apple_audio: Failed opening /dev/fd/63, error in ExtAudioFileOpenURL (-40)
AUBIO ERROR: source_wavread: could not find RIFF header in /dev/fd/63
AUBIO ERROR: source: failed creating aubio source with /dev/fd/63 at samplerate 0 with hop_size 256
Error: could not open input file /dev/fd/63
```

The problem doesn't seem to lie with `sox`, since this command works fine:

```
cat <(sox -q -d -t wav -) > output.wav
```

It creates an `output.wav` file that nothing seems to have trouble playing, except `aubiopitch` of course:

```
$ aubiopitch output.wav
Segmentation fault: 11
```

What's going on here? Is the issue with the RIFF header having the wrong length set?

If it matters, I'm running OSX 10.7.5 and I recompiled aubio to work with my older OSX version.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ sox -q -d -t wav - | aubiopitch -i -
```

When compiled with libsndfile support, `'-' = stdin`, so the above command could give the following output.

```
sox WARN wav: Length in output .wav header will be wrong since can't seek to fix it
0.000000 0.000000
0.005805 707.323486
0.011610 [...]
```

If you compiled aubio with more sources (`avcodec` or `apple_audio`), you will get more warnings. You can hide these warnings by redirecting `stderr` to `/dev/null`. Here is an example with `aubioonset`:

```
$ ( sox -q -d -t wav - | aubioonset -i - ) 2> /dev/null
0.000000
0.096871
0.279297
[...]
```