# How to use aubio to get frequency of each tone in a series of tones in python

Tags: python, pitch-tracking, aubio

I found some example code for getting pitch using aubio, but I'm not sure what to change to get it to display the pitch in second increments:

```
import sys 
from aubio import source, pitch, freqtomidi

if len(sys.argv) < 2:
    print "Usage: %s <filename> [samplerate]" % sys.argv[0]
    sys.exit(1)

filename = sys.argv[1]
downsample = 1 
samplerate = 44100 / downsample
if len( sys.argv ) > 2: samplerate = int(sys.argv[2])

win_s = 4096 / downsample # fft size
hop_s = 512  / downsample # hop size


s = source(filename, samplerate, hop_s)
samplerate = s.samplerate

tolerance = 0.8 


pitch_o = pitch("yin", win_s, hop_s, samplerate)
pitch_o.set_tolerance(tolerance)

pitches = []
confidences = []

total_frames = 0 
while True:
    samples, read = s() 
    pitch = pitch_o(samples)[0]
    pitch = int(round(pitch))
    confidence = pitch_o.get_confidence()
    #if confidence < 0.8: pitch = 0.
    print "%f %f %f" % (total_frames / float(samplerate), pitch, confidence)
    pitches += [pitch]
    confidences += [confidence]
    total_frames += read
    if read < hop_s: break
```

Also, is it possible for me to do this directly from output instead of a wav file?

Comment: hi can you explain what does confidence, pitch and samplerate mean since  i'm new to this audio processing and i am wokring on similar use case but i am not finding a good start.

Answer (score 1):

This script (also at [`aubio/python/demos/demo_pitch.py`](https://github.com/aubio/aubio/blob/master/python/demos/demo_pitch.py)) extracts pitch candidate for every audio frame (here *512./44100 * 1000 = 11.6ms*).

> display the pitch in second increments

What do you mean by "in second increments"? The 'overall' pitch for each consecutive 1-second long segments? You could take `np.median(pitches)`.

The new pitch after each note change? You could process the output and group similar pitch candidates into notes.

Or just use `aubionotes` directly.

> do this directly from output

From which "output" do you mean?

See also [run aubiopitch continuously on a file descriptor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26186132/run-aubiopitch-continuously-on-a-file-descriptor).

Please ask your aubio questions @ https://github.com/aubio/aubio.